# Trans_status Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good Day!

I have trans_start - trans_complete in model,

```
public function insert_user($name, $desc)
{
$this->db->trans_start(TRUE);
$this->db->set('Name', $name);
$this->db->set('Desc', $desc);
$this->db->insert('user');
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
$this->db->trans_complete();
return $id;
```

I am wondering if it is possible if `trans_status === TRUE` then it will go to another model like this:

```
if ($this->db->trans_status() === TRUE)
    {
        insert_access($get);
    }
```

This is the model:

```
public function insert_access($get)
    {
        $data = $this->input->post('pTableData');
        $tableData = json_decode($data,TRUE);
        foreach ($tableData as $get)
        {
            $this->db->set('UserID', $id);
            $this->db->set('AccessName', $get['accessName']);
            $this->db->set('Password', $get['password']);
            $this->db->insert('access');
            $id_access = $this->db->insert_id();

            return $id_access ;
        }
    }
```

And get the `return $id` in `function insert_user($name, $desc)` so that I can use it in `function insert_access($get)` in the set `$this->db->set('UserID', $id);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as you said:

```
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
if ($this->db->trans_status() === TRUE)
{
    $this->insert_access($id);                //if in the same model
    $this->another_model->insert_access($id); //if some other model
}
```

But, I see in your function, `insert_access($get)`, you have used, `$data = $this->input->post('pTableData');`, which btw is not possible because you are calling this function directly from another model function.
To make it work, you could send the `post data` from your `insert_user` function to your `insert_access` function.

Comment: Thanks! I just need to figure out about the post dat!:)

Comment: I just have one question. Is it allowed to put the trans_status in controller eventhough my trans_start-trans_complete is in the model?

Comment: Even better, from the model if true return the if back to the controller or return 0, check the return value in your controller, and call the `insert_access` with the `post data` and the returned `id`.